# Linking to external Scala API docs in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, api, intellij-idea, documentation

Despite adding an [external URL](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/) to the JavaDocs of my Scala 2.10.4 SDK library setup in IntelliJ 15.0.1 (Project Settings -> Global Libraries -> `scala-sdk-2.10.4` -> `JavaDocs`) [see screenshot below], the little blue arrow that (should) link to external documentation in the quick documentation viewer (`[F1]`) does not link to the external Scala documentation, instead remaining grayed out. Neither does the keyboard shortcut to view external documentation work (`[Shift]-[F1]`). How do I link to the external ScalaDoc SDK API documents, so that I can quickly open the online documentation (locally or on scala-lang.org, doesn't matter) for the content my cursor is on in the IntelliJ editor in the browser?

[image: Scala SDK Project Settings]

Comment: Same here. It woks for java, but I can't get it to work for Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is still an outstanding feature for the Scala plugin:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5550

*This was added 4 years ago and commented upon as quick to implement - perhaps chase JetBrains to implement*